# Python - Iterating non-integer items in list for a loop

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am doing a project which involves web scraping in Python. I'm using the BeautifulSoup and Selenium libraries. At one point in my script, I'm collecting all of the URL tags with the text of the links.

```
link_click = driver.find_elements_by_link_text(
    'Fall/Winter 2017-2018 Course Schedule')
```

Then, I count to see how many links there actually are in the list that I've created.

```
len(link_click)
```

The following is a function which I will need to run later.

```
def get_course_info():
    url = driver.current_url
    response = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
    course = soup.find_all('p')
    course_code = print(course[0].text[3:][:9])
    course_cat = print(course[0].text[3:][:4])
    course_name = print(course[0].text[22:])
    course_desc = print(course[3].text)
    results = soup.findAll("td", {"valign": "TOP","width" : "15%"})[1::2]
    list_of_inner_text = [x.text for x in results]
    final = list(set(list_of_inner_text))
    instructors = ', '.join(final)
    print(instructors)
```

I use this block of code to execute what I need to do with the links.

```
course_select = link_click[1].click();
get_course_info()
```

My question is that I am currently passing in 1 from the index of `link_click` to the function. I would like to loop through it so that all 33 of the links can be passed into the `course_select` and `get_course_info` functions.

Comment: I can't see how this wouldn't be as simple as iterating over a `range` list, what's the matter doing that?

Comment: Are you just looking for `for link in links:`? The `for` loop doesn't care whether you have a list of integers, a list of strings, or a list of functions that take file objects and return launch graphs; it can loop over anything.

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar A range list won't work with this data type since they are URLs. Unless you know a different way to do that?

Comment: You can always iterate over any *iterable*, as mentioned by @abarnert. But you can also go the expensive way and iterate over the indexes using the range list.

Comment: @abarnert Yes that is what I am looking for, but how do I pass that into the course_select function? I tried this but it requires an integer or a slice.

Comment: @abarnert Would you be able to show me how to format the code for that part? This is how I am currently doing it.    for link in link_click:
    course_select = link_click[link].click();
    get_course_info()

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. I don't see a function named `course_select` that you're calling and passing things into anywhere.

Comment: @abarnert My mistake, the course_select variable. Instead of putting [1] in here course_select = link_click[1].click(); what should I put?

Comment: @express_v2 I still don't understand what you're asking. If you want to click and get a result for each thing in `link_click`, just do `for thing in link_click:` then `course_select = thing.click()` and then whatever you want to do with each `course_select`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a loop that your are trying to achieve, here it is:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Fall/Winter 2017-2018 Course Schedule')

if len(links) >= 1:
    for link in links:
        link.click()
        time.sleep(2) #wait for page load
        get_course_info()
else:
    print ("No links found")
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for.